# Weak rules in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Having written basic logic solvers (Sudoku et al) I'm trying to learn more real-world Prolog by writing a hostel bed allocation system.

The "Must" rules work (e.g. "The room holds 3 people", "X must share a room with Y") but I am having a problem with "Should" rules that can be broken (e.g. "People should stay in the same bed for their stay - but can move rooms if needed").

Can Prolog handle weak rules where the logic isn't binary? I've come across probabilistic programming extensions, but don't see this as a probabilistic problem.

If not, what approaches/languages should I investigate instead?

Alternatively, is it the way I've framed the problem, and I need to think about continuity from night to night as guests come and go a different way?

Comment: This is a very broadly stated question and I am afraid it should be closed. If you show some code and the problem you are having it would be much easier to answer.

Comment: I can add code later, though as it doesn't handle weak rules it's not going to be particularly helpful. I have stated the problem I am having in the text (paragraphs 2 & 3) - is it not clear to you?

Comment: No, apparently not clear to me. There are way too many ways to achieve what you want. The simplest is simply to take advantage of Prolog's non-determinism and allow for multiple solutions. But without code and a clear statement of what your input is and what output you expect all you can get is opinions and suggestions, or someone miraculously taking the time to code a complete solution based on a vaguely worded question.

Comment: I think since prolog is base on first order logic it is impossible

Comment: @whd Prolog is a general purpose programming language. It is also turing-complete. What do you mean by "impossible" exactly?

Comment: A Prolog program's structure does have an order of execution to it as far as what clauses are considered for a given query. One way to do what you want (and I may be oversimplifying a bit here) is to have the optional requirement be needed for the success of earlier clause(s), but not have that optional requirement in later clauses. For example, with the two clauses: `p :- a, b.` and `p :- a.` the condition `a` is required for `p` to succeed, but `b` is not required for success, although is the first option considered.

Comment: If you have rules that can be broken, this would probably indicate that there is a kind of cost function involved, and you try to optimize that cost function (for example, minimize the number of non-mandatory rules that are broken).  It would help if you could explain more clearly how you would like the program to deal with non-mandatory rules.

Comment: in SWI-Prolog, see library(clpfd), there are scheduling helpers, that will help to solve efficiently the allocation. Will require some time to learn to model your problem, so start with a *very* simple task.

Comment: Thanks all - I will delete this question and repost in a week or so when I've written up a detailed question. I thought detail was frowned upon as it feels like "doing someone's homework for them", but very happy that's not the case!

Comment: Actually detail is encouraged, because it shows effort on the part of the one asking the question. Very general questions feel more like asking others to do one's thinking for them. ;) But in this case, it's actually a good question and an interesting one. Just not in alignment with stackoverflow.com charter.

Comment: @lurker (and at OP of course) There are simply other forums much better suited for a question like this one. As it stands, this question is rather an invitation to a discussion. There is Reddit, there is comp.lang.prolog, there are IRC channels, etc. The question is neither uninteresting nor bad, just too broad.

Comment: @Boris I agree and I think I was saying that the question is off topic for this forum. I was just saying that, nonetheless, it is an interesting question.

Comment: I have finally written the detailed question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610341/assigning-attendees-to-bedsbeds-soft-constraints-and-cost-functions Your input much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

In the literature, your "weak rules" are usually called **soft constraints**, as opposed to **hard constraints** which must be satisfied.  As already mentioned in the comments, soft constraints are often handled by introducing a **cost function**.  Every violated soft constraint contributes a certain cost to the total value of the cost function. A good/optimal solution can then be found by looking for a solution that reduces/minimizes the total cost.

In Prolog, you can implement this via code that computes **all** solutions, including all combinations of satisfied and unsatisfied soft constraints.  Along with each solution, you compute the associated value of the cost function.

Here is an example.  As is often the case in practice, the cost function has several components.  In this case, it is made up of costs associated with the individual rooms, plus a penalty when consecutive rooms are not equal.

```
solution([Room1,Room2], TotalCost) :-
    Rooms = [a-90, b-50, c-20, d-70],       % Room-Cost data
    member(Room1-Cost1, Rooms),             % select Room1
    member(Room2-Cost2, Rooms),             % select Room2
    prefer_equal(Room1, Room2, Penalty),    % penalty for different rooms
    Room2 \= c,                             % some additional constraint
    TotalCost is Cost1+Cost2+Penalty.       % cost function

prefer_equal(R,  R,   0).                   % no penalty if equal
prefer_equal(R1, R2, 30) :- R1\=R2.         % penalty if not equal
```

This predicate gives 12 alternative solutions with costs ranging from 100 to 190.  The details of how to best get from here to an optimal solution is somewhat dependent on your Prolog system.  In [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org) you would do the following:

```
?- branch_and_bound:minimize(solution(Rooms, Cost), Cost).
Found a solution with cost 180
Found a solution with cost 170
Found a solution with cost 100
Rooms = [b, b]
Cost = 100
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```

This should illustrate the general idea.  Unfortunately, this technique isn't really scalable when used with plain Prolog, because it can dramatically increase the search space.  It is therefore usually employed together with **constraint solving** techniques, as implemented in a number of modern Prolog systems.