# Assigning people to beds - approaches to automate

Tags: python, scipy, prolog, clpfd, constraint-programming

I help with a youth camp every year. Assigning attendees to bedrooms is a massive task - there are 92 bedrooms and the event runs for a week, with attendees staying for varying lengths of time, and beds needing to be reused.

It currently takes a volunteer ~a week to assign people to rooms. There are lots of rules to follow, and as not all attendees stay for the full week assignment is done on a night by night basis.

I want to automate the task. The programming language and computational cost are implementation details, and I can format the input data/rules however needed (inc code generation). Anything that saves hours of tedium...

### Available techniques

I have no domain expertise, so first I have to understand possible approaches.

Constraint programming seemed the obvious approach as there are rules to follow. However the rules aren't binary, and a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36164781/119750) introduced me to *soft constraints* and *cost functions*.

When I read up on cost functions it pointed me to machine learning and neural networks. These are popular but I believe need sets of data to train them, which is something I don't have - I could create, but that'd take more time overall than doing assignment manually. And I know the constraints already: I don't have to deduce them from data.

- Q: Is a cost function in Prolog different to in machine learning?
- Q: Is machine learning a 'fit' for this problem?
- Q: Are there other approaches I've overlooked?

I can't find room assignment problems being discussed on the web, in journals etc; It must be common so I am missing some domain-specific terminology. With hospitals and hotels needing it, I'm sure it is well researched.

- Q: What is a bed-assignment problem called in the literature?

### Time-based assignments

I also have a conceptual problem. I can see how I solve for one night, but how do I think of modelling multiple nights?

The constraint solver (or other technique) is unaware of time (and won't know `2016-09-05` comes before `2016-09-06`), but I need to input the nights people stay and see the assignments per-night.

- Q: How should I consider time series?

### Conceptually grasping the output

The second is: How would the system output which bedrooms people are assigned to? In a Prolog sudoku solver (for example) there can be multiple solutions, but that's with hard constraints. With fuzzy constraints, would I end up with a probability that person X is in Room Y, and a probability they're also in Room Z (a quantum superposition if you like)?

- Q: What will the output be like?

### Partial solutions are OK

A first-pass assignment which has to be manually adjusted would save time. As would manually assigning the 'complicated' attendees (like night security, who sleep in a particular room) and letting the computer do the rest.

- Q: Does this make the problem easier to solve?

#### My attempt

Originally I thought of resurrecting my one-semester of Prolog knowledge from 13 years ago, and setting constraints for all criteria. This worked for a very simple cases, but I failed once I moved beyond "must" criteria to grey-rules and compromises.

### Sample Rules (constraints)

All rules have different priorities. To simplify I've grouped by `must`, `should` and `nice`.

- `must` Same gender in room

  - Unless over-ridden by "Must share with" option e.g. couples
- `must` People who need disabled-friendly rooms get them
- `must` If the attendee needs a room with a cot for their baby, they must get it
- `must` Attendees who specify "Must Share with X" or "Must Share with Y & Z" must be assigned the same room

  - They may not be staying for the same number of nights (e.g. A stays for Mon-Thu, B for Tue-Fri). Blocking out beds for the entire period is OK)
  - the "Must Share With" relationship can be unidirectional or bidirectional - I can implement either
- `must/should` If an attendee needs a single room, they must get it unless there's no possible solution
- `should` Group attendees in rooms by roles, e.g. "Youth", "Youth leaders", "Cooks", "Leaders". Some roles are more suitable to mix than others.
- `should` Minimise room-hopping: once you have a bed, stay in it for all nights. Unless there's no possible solution
- `should` Couples are prioritised rooms with double beds

  - (I haven't figured out how to make a rule for this, which doesn't assume all "Must Share With" relations are couples. At the moment it's done with human knowledge)
- `nice` Group attendees in rooms by university they attend (where applicable)
- `nice` Prioritise rooms with en-suite facilities to non-youth roles

There are more rules (e.g people with dietary requirements must stay in a particular building) but this provides enough examples.

The venue charges per-bed not per-room, so minimising the number of rooms used is **NOT** important - this year at least.

Similar assignment has to be done for attendees to dining rooms & washing-up rotas, but both are much simpler.

### Sample data set

```
rooms:
    room1:
        building: Building1
        capacity: 2
        is_ensuite: yes
        has_cot: yes
    room2:
        building: Building2
        capacity: 4
        is_ensuite: no
        has_cot: yes
    room3:
        building: Building1
        capacity: 2
        is_ensuite: no
        has_cot: yes
    room4:
        building: Building1
        capacity: 4
        is_ensuite: no
        has_cot: no
    room5:
        building: Building1
        capacity: 4
        is_ensuite: no
        has_cot: no
---
people:
    albert:
        must_share_with: @brenda
        needs_cot: yes
        role: leader
        gender: m
        arrive: 2016-09-05
        depart: 2016-09-10
    brenda:
        role: no role
        gender: f
        arrive: 2016-09-06
        depart: 2016-09-09
    steve:
        role: student
        university: Cambridge
        gender: m
        arrive: 2016-09-07
        depart: 2016-09-09
    jason:
        role: student
        university: Bristol
        gender: m
        arrive: 2016-09-07
        depart: 2016-09-09
    brian:
        role: tech
        gender: m
        arrive: 2016-09-05
        depart: 2016-09-10
    clare:
        role: speaker
        gender: f
        arrive: 2016-09-08
        depart: 2016-09-09
    george:
        role: band/after hours
        gender: m
        arrive: 2016-09-07
        depart: 2016-09-08
    sarah:
        role: band/after hours
        gender: f
        arrive: 2016-09-07
        depart: 2016-09-08
    john:
        role: band/after hours
        gender: m
        arrive: 2016-09-08
        depart: 2016-09-09
    janet:
        role: band/after hours
        gender: f
        arrive: 2016-09-08
        depart: 2016-09-09
```

#### Sample outcomes

```
| Room  | Capacity | 2016-09-05 | 2016-09-06     | 2016-09-07     | 2016-09-08     | 2016-09-09     | 2016-09-10 | 
|-------|----------|------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|------------| 
| room1 | 2        | albert     | albert, brenda | albert, brenda | albert, brenda | albert, brenda | albert     | 
| room2 | 4        |            |                | jason, steve   | jason, steve   | jason, steve   |            | 
| room3 | 2        | brian      | brian          | brian          | brian          | brian          | brian      | 
| room4 | 4        |            |                | george         | john           |                |            | 
| room5 | 4        |            |                | sarah          | janet          |                |            |
```

Or (whether this is acceptable depends which roles can share rooms, e.g. band members go to bed at 3am, tech gets up at 6am):

```
| Room  | Capacity | 2016-09-05 | 2016-09-06     | 2016-09-07     | 2016-09-08     | 2016-09-09     | 2016-09-10 | 
|-------|----------|------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|------------| 
| room1 | 2        | albert     | albert, brenda | albert, brenda | albert, brenda | albert, brenda | albert     | 
| room2 | 4        |            |                | jason, steve   | jason, steve   | jason, steve   |            | 
| room3 | 2        | brian      | brian          | brian, george  | brian, john    | brian          | brian      | 
| room4 | 4        |            |                | sarah          | janet          |                |            | 
| room5 | 4        |            |                |                |                |                |            |
```

Comment: @lurker Oh dear, I'm sorry. I am clearly not good at asking questions where I don't know the answer. Would revising it and adding bullet point questions help?

Comment: @lurker: there we go. I can split it into multiple StackOverflow questions if preferable.

Comment: Here are some random thoughts pertaining to the questions. I could see using a weighting factor to handle the "should" items. Possible results would be collected and the highest weight solution chosen. A single result has a weight and, I suppose, a list of discrete tuples consisting of date, person, and room. I think the hopping mimimization dictates the solution knowing something about relative order of dates, but that's easy I think (Prolog sees `Y-M-D` as a term, `-(-(Y,M),D)`). See `@</2` and `@>`, so `2016-9-10 @< 2016-10-1` is true in Prolog.

Comment: Perhaps separate out the philosophical questions from those more direct to the problem.

Comment: Hi - I feel a bit bad that this got closed when you'd obviously put in a lot of effort.  I think you could google "hotel room assignment problem" to get into your problem.  It's also not dissimilar to a timetabling problem (e.g. for a school / university).  There is literature on that too.  Lots of approaches have been written about - evolutionary algos, integer programming, dynamic programming and so on. Also - do not despair about your attempts - this is a hard combinatorial problem.  It's made a little easier by the fact that you don't have to minimise the number of rooms.

Comment: @JRichardSnape Thanks that's much appreciated. Believe me I have googled for that over the last month (between posting my first "too brief" and second "too long" questions)! I will have another go and a search on those approaches you mention, I only came across integer programming in my previous searching.

Comment: What I don't understand is: as I provided the detail missing in my first question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148764/weak-rules-in-prolog) as requested, why is this not a "good question"? What on Earth makes a good question?